# Switch that can be powered over Ethernet?

Tags: poe

We are looking for an 8 port switch that can be powered over ethernet. Looks like a device like this is a powered device (PD). I've heard that cisco makes switch products like this but don't know how to locate them.

I did come across this 5 port startec switch... but more ports would be ideal. This switch does not need to power any additional PoE devices besides itself.
[https://www.amazon.com/Port-Gigabit-Ethernet-Switch-PoE-Powered/dp/B01273JAD0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01273JAD0)

This is the current candidate PSE switch:
Cisco (SG300-52P-K9-NA) 52-Port Gigabit PoE Managed Switch
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00BHZJMB0/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BHZJMB0)

I would prefer cisco or linksys because I'm familiar with those brands but reliability and value are the key items. Cisco can sometimes be expensive.

Comment: Are you looking for something powered by 802.3something-standard PoE? Does the switch need to power other PoE devices? Do you already have a PoE switch that you are connecting this to, or you expecting it to include some sort of injector? Do you have a budget in mind? Are you preferring Cisco brand specifically due to it being what other hardware you use, or is it just a name of a networking hardware manufacturer you've heard of? Just about any networking manufacturer has something along these lines, but it may be helpful for you to [edit] with more details on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a candidate switch that can be powered entirely over ethernet but I would like to know of more switch options if others would help contribute an answer:
NETGEAR 8-Port Gigabit Ethernet Smart Managed Pro Switch (GS108T-300NAS)
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07PS6Z162/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PS6Z162)